# Inverse Image of a Regular Value an Orientable Submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $f:M^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth map, and let $c\in N$ be a regular value. When is $f^{-1}(c)$ an orientable manifold?

Note: I know by regular value thm, $f^{-1}(c)$ is a smooth $n-1$ dimensional submanifold of $M$, w/o boundary, and I am aware that if $M$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ then this is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f^{-1}(c)$ is orientable if and only if $f^{-1}(c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon)$ is orientable, assuming sufficiently small $\epsilon$.

If $M$ itself is orientable then that is a sufficient condition, because $f^{-1}(c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon)$ is an open subset and therefore orientable.

I don't think there's much more you can say than that.

Comment: Oh okay, that's too bad... what if $M$ is $S^3$? Does that change anything? I was trying to do this for that case and was wondering if there was a more general statement.

Comment: @Pilo: I added a clause addressing orientable $M$.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense. Thanks.